# How to send mail in Java having only the from and to and subject and message?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using the following code to send mail:

```
protected void mailSettings() {
    Object lookedUp = null;
    String mailSettingValues[] = null;
    try {
        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        lookedUp = initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/mailsettings");
        mailSettingValues = lookedUp.toString().split(",");
        smtphost = mailSettingValues[0];
        port = mailSettingValues[1];
        username = mailSettingValues[2];
        password = mailSettingValues[3];
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    m_properties = new Properties();
    m_properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtphost);
    m_properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    m_properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    m_properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);

    m_Session = Session.getDefaultInstance(m_properties,
            new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

}

public void sendMail(String mail_from, String mail_to, String mail_subject,
        String m_body) {
    try {
        m_simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(m_Session);
        m_fromAddress = new InternetAddress(mail_from);
        m_toAddress = new InternetAddress(mail_to);

        m_simpleMessage.setFrom(m_fromAddress);
        m_simpleMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, m_toAddress);
        m_simpleMessage.setSubject(mail_subject);

        m_simpleMessage.setContent(m_body, "text/plain");

        Transport.send(m_simpleMessage);
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As of this code we need to have email from address and the password for the same, but I would like to send mail to `to_email` address without the authentication(getting user password).

How can this be done?

I need to do the following things:

1. get the from address from properties or context file
2. get the to address from properties or context file
3. send mail to `to_address` without authenticating the from address

Comment: If the mail host requires authentication and you have the credentials (address + password) why do you want to circumvent that? Why don't you just read them from some secure place and provide them to the mail host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SimpleSendEmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String host = "your smtp host";
        String to = "bbbb@ddddd.com";
        String from = "xxxx@yyy.com";
        String subject = "My First Email";
        String messageText = "I am sending a message using the"
                + " JavaMail API.\n" + "Here type your message.";
        boolean sessionDebug = false;
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.host", host);
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        // Set debug on the Session so we can see what is going on
        // Passing false will not echo debug info, and passing true
        // will.
        session.setDebug(sessionDebug);
        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] address = { new InternetAddress(to) };
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setText(messageText);

            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a general sense, it's not possible.

You **need** an SMTP server to be able to send email.  So you'll need to know the details of this server to make the SMTP connection - at the very least, the hostname (and the port, though this can usually be assumed to be the default value of 25).

Then the SMTP server itself will *probably* require authentication.  In that case, you'll need to have the sufficient information available to keep it happy - probably a principal(/username) and creditials(/password).

If you find an SMTP server that will allow anonymous relaying, i.e. allow you to send mail through it without authenticating first, then of course you can skip the authentication step, and won't need a password.

But you do still need an SMTP server to do the sending - so you can't somehow send an email with "just" a pair of addresses.

Comment: it is possible see my answer below

Comment: @Learner in your answer below, you **are** defining the `host` property in addition to the pair of email addresses (and the message contents themselves).  And as per my answer, your example will only work if the SMTP host allows anonymous relaying.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use SMTP authentication because any SMTP server that allows public anonymous relaying will be black listed as a source of spam.

You can either run your own local SMTP server that allows relaying or depending on the application server you are using you might be able to configure the server to place authentication sessions in JNDI and just look them up. You wouldn't have to code the username and password but you'd still have to supply them to the app server.